# Ideals of the operator algebra

Tags: banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra. Is there any relation ship between  two-sided closed ideals of $A$ and two-sided closed ideals of the operator algebra $\mathscr B(A)$? Is there any characterization for ideals of $\mathscr B(A)$?

Comment: Just a simple observation. If $A = \mathbb{C}^n$, then $B(A) \cong M_n(\mathbb{C})$. In this case, $A$ has $2^n$ distinct ideals: one for each subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. On the other hand, $B(A)$ is simple and has only $2$ ideals.

Comment: As for your second question, the ideal structure of $\mathscr B(A)$ is usually a complicated issue. See p. 2 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4800v1.pdf

Actually there are very few Banach algebras for which the ideal structure of $\mathscr B(A)$ is completely understood.